# SQL Server Reporting Subscriptions

Tags: sql, reporting-services

I have a SQL Server 2014 Enterprise with SSRS configured. I have custom reports built via Report Builder and subscriptions via SSRS. I am currently emailing MHTML via the subscriptions, but this doesn't allow you to expand the rows in the tables.

[image]

As above, that row, when you browse to SSRS via web browser, can be expanded to see it's child items. Is there anyway you can get this to come expanded in the MHTML report sent via the sub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately drill down only works in Report Manager or the Excel rendering extension. The HTML generated excludes the hidden items. Mentioned in last section of https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd207042.aspx

Because of this I send Excel reports in my subscriptions.

The solution would be to get the report to always show the expanded rows when exported to MHTML. http://blog.hoegaerden.be/2011/01/18/ssrs-hideshow-items-dependant-on-export-format/